# Meteor collection update focus and blur latency

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, minimongo

I'm trying to save user content on blur and am encountering a weird UI freeze after the save that I've never seen before.

A simplified version of the template:

```
{{#each UserSession.getQuestions}}
   <textearea class='question'>{{UserSession.getVal this._id}}</teaxtarea>
{{/each}}
```

In other words, we iterate over a cursor from the `Questions` collection that selects all questions a user must answer, and we populate the `textarea` with a value from the `UserSessions` collection that contains this user's response to that question. For what it's worth, the `textarea` is actually in its own template (there are other things to show in there so i figured best to keep them isolated).

The user can modify the content of his response, and then I have an event handler that basically does this:

```
"blur .question": function(e) {
   var val = $(e.target).val();
   var questionId = this._id;
   var userSessionId = Meteor.user().getSessionId();
   var modifier = {$set: {}};
   modifier["$set"]["questions." + questionId + "] = val;
   UserSessions.update({_id: userSessionId}, modifier);
}
```

The update succeeds but the browser freezes for about a second after the save executes, so that if the blur is triggered by a user clicking on another element, that element doesn't come into focus cleanly. This is a problem because I also want to do periodic saves while the user is typing, but when I do that, the hiccup interrupts the typing: the resulting experience is pretty brutal.

The interesting thing is that the browser only seems to freeze when the property being updated is an object or in a list. In other words:

`UserSessions.update({_id: userSessionId}, {$set: {"questions.questionId": "someVal"}})` causes the freeze, as does `UserSessions.update({_id: userSessionId}, {$set: {"lastSavedAt": new Date()}})`.

However, `UserSessions.update({_id: userSessionId}, {$set: {"someOtherProp": "someVal"}})` works fine.

I've tried several different approaches, including an async client-side pattern and executing the save via Meteor Method in a `if (Meteor.isServer)` block -- all the same result. Must be something to do with the publication updating, but it happens even when i set the publish function query to `{reactive: false}`.

I'm out of ideas. Your help, as always, is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
db

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out. For anyone else who has this problem, if you're using Iron Router you should check it for un-necessary dependencies. In this case it was the router being re-run that clogged up the works, because the data hook included a reactive find request on the UserSessions collection. I set reactive to false and specified the fields to prevent a recomputation, and everything smoothed itself out.